# Flutter Image assets and Stream values only render after user interactions

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

When opening the application for the first time images and stream values are not rendering until I tap on the screen or start scrolling. Made sure that the snapshot.data is printing out the correct values before returning the widget in the stream builder.

```
  Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Image.asset(
        'assets/profile_image.png',
        height: 36.0,
        width: 36.0,
      ),
      SizedBox(width: 10.0),
      StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream: context.read<UserBloc>().balanceStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print('ConnectionState is ${snapshot.connectionState}');
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.active:
              print('Value is ${snapshot.data}');
              return NonScalingTextView(
                "\$ ${snapshot.data}",
                style: TitleTiny,
              );
              break;
            default:
              return Container();
          }
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Performing some user interaction or hot reloading or hot restarting the application after first launch, the widgets render as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an Authentication Bloc parenting the Material App. Inside I had a User Bloc created on successful Auth. I had the above issues when this was the case. The issue was only happening on the Widgets rendered based on the states emitted by the User Bloc. So rather than returning these widgets on state changes I changed my listener to navigate to these widgets on state changes. Now in order to call on my User Bloc from this navigated route, I had to move the User Bloc on top of the Material App. And doing this solved my issue.

This solved it but I still don't know what caused the former architecture to fail. If anyone can explain me, it'd be great.